# VLC does not start after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, vlc

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04; the upgrade went without any (obvious) issues.

After the upgrade, when I start VLC - be it from terminal (`vlc &`) or from the UI - it does not start. It just does nothing... no errors, no windows open, nothing.

`ps -fea | grep vlc` returns the following:
[image]

I tried reinstalling VLC (I'm using `snap`), no effect.

If I try to execute the bash script myself (`bash /snap/vlc/3078/bin/vlc-snap-wrapper.sh`), I get `"Unsupported architecture for this app build"`.

Having looked at the bash script, it seems that `$SNAP_ARCH` leads to that error; the variable itself is empty (o.O)

How should I approach this?

Comment: Is the 5.15 kernel installed?

Comment: @Mahler, yes - 5.15.0-56-generic